# Is it possible to force the Google speech synthesis engine to pronounce individual phonemes?

Tags: speech-synthesis

I wish to have an app makes individual sounds of letters (phonemes) and I'm wondering if, rather than record them all myself, I can force Google's speech synthesis engine to give me individual sounds.

For example, inputting "s" says "ess", the letter name rather than making the sound of an s as used the beginning of sandwich. I appreciate there are different "s" sounds (ass vs as) so there would obviously need to be some sort of table of phonemes... does anyone know if such a thing?

I hope this was the right place to ask! Thanks  in advance for your help.

Mike

Comment: Do you know the difference between phonemes and "sounds of letters"?

Comment: Did you stop reading at the first sentence? My apologies for perhaps mis-phrasing my question (I'm not a linguist  myself, so just feeling me way at the moment).

I'm trying to break down a word into it's spoken constituent parts (the phonemes, am I right?) - but google's speech synthesis just uses the names for the letters. I was wondering if it's possible to force it to give you just one phoneme? (obviously some words are single phonemes, so those ones are doable).

Any ideas?